# Why does my MVC Action not see my ajax passed object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ajax call works but the passed object is empty.

Its a simple setup of passing a cart object to  a controller action.

The call happens but    man  is empty when it hits the Action.

The paylod being sent(in chrome) is:

```
{"man":"testtext2"}
```

The response is:

```
{"man":null}
```

> .net cartitem:

```
public class Cartitem
    {
        public string man { get; set; }
    }
```

> Javascript cartitem:

```
 class cartitem {
            constructor(  _man, ) {
               this.man = _man;
            }
        }
```

> Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddToCart(Cartitem myCartitem)
{
  //ERROR: cartitem values are coming in empty 
  return Json(myCartitem);
}
```

> Javascript

```
$(".AddLink").click(function () {

  var json = JSON.stringify(c);
  var cartitem = JSON.stringify({
            'man': 'testtext2',
        });

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart")',  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: cartitem,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Data Back: " + data.man);
            }
        });

});
```

Edit
To remove a a lot of red hearings, I've simplified the code so  its one single string(man).
The result is the same, MyCartitem is coming in empty.

Comment: You're sending string for `qty` and `price` when they should be int and decimal respectively. It's also not a good idea to name the class and argument the same thing. I'd suggest changing the class name in C# to `CartItem`

Comment: Adding to above comment,  Use the variables which you defined `mpn, qty` etc in `var dataObject = JSON.stringify({
            'qty': qty,
        });`

Comment: @Satpal they'd still be strings, as that's what `attr()` returns. OP, use `data()` to get the attribute values, or run the relevant ones through `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`

Comment: This commented out line `//var c = new cartitem(qty, man, mpn, desc, price, sku);` wouldn't work because class should be `cartItem` as Javascript is case sensitive. I have added integer and decimal values in dataObject for qty and mpm. The code you provided worked for me and I'm getting values in controller method and they come back to the page in response. I believe the problem is you're getting some null values from Html tag attributes in the beginning of your code and sku is string empty.

Comment: I edited the code to  take account of all comments but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there anything in mvc /.net core that stops json being 'seen'.?

Answer (score 0):

Add [FromBody]  to the Action method e.g

public ActionResult AddToCart([FromBody] Cartitem myCartitem)
        {

}

2 days lost!